# Should I use a static IP address? If so what kind?

Tags: port, ipv6, home-server, ipv4, dynamic-dns

Last night I managed to get my local PC running as a server using port 80 and my IP address.

After restarting my machine it stopped working.

I was told I need to make a static IP address.  My question is should I set my IPv4 or IPv6 address to be static?

Comment: Could you provide more info on exactly what you are trying to accomplish?  Network layout?

Comment: I want my PC to be accessable to the net. So when I am ni college I can back up my work by going to myip:80/index.html.  Or if I make an example website I can put it on my server before my hosting company

Comment: Also, local network or do plan on getting to it from outside the network too? Either way you'll want to give the PC a static IP in the network (192.168.1.x usually) and find a solution for a static external IP (like dyndns)

Comment: What type of internet service do you have? A static IP can only be given from your ISP, but if you have a constant connection service (cable, fios) then the IP shouldn't change very often. Contact your ISP to see if you can get a static IP (although this usually costs more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static IPs are used to make sure that they will always be accessible from the outside work at a consistent address. While it is possible to do without one with something like [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), if you are running a server that is meant to be externally accessible, you should have a static IP.

With regard to the IPv4 or IPv6 part, your should support both, though it may not be strictly necessary at this point.

Comment: If it's just for your personal use Dynamic DNS service will work just fine. I like freedns.afraid.org

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may be able to provide a static IP or as suggested, DynDNS will work with many routers.  The router will allow you to fowrard specific ports(like 80)  to your PC and it will allow you to assign a static IP to the computer.  The router will add a layer of protection between the PC and the Web.  You would forwward Port 80 to the internal IP of the PC.  Most home/SMB routers have wizard like interfaces to set much of this up.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your machine might have stopped the connection to the server and you need to start the server again.  Or set it to run when windows starts, typically done by setting it to run as a service in windows.

It's rare that restarting a computer would cause you to get a new IP.  Restarting a Router might. But a Computer, wouldn't.  The only case that springs to mind, is if you have a DSL Modem Card, then your ISP might assign you another IP

Why don't you restart your machine and see if your IP actually changes?

Are you sure that your IP changed?

You should check your IP while connected, and after restarting your computer (run the IPCONFIG command from the cmd prompt). See if it changes.  If it doesn't, then this problem has nothing to do wit dynamic and static IPs.

There are servies others have mentioned like DYNDNS, where you don't get a static IP, but you get a Domain name, and that points to your dynamic IP.  Your computer or your router have a feature or software that send your IP to the dyndns people and the IP associated with the domain gets updated to your latest IP, and people just access the domain(which doesn't change).